# specific LNK2001 error with boost::filesystem and VC++2010

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2010, lnk2001

I am stumped on this one.

I have some cross platform code that I am trying to compile with Win7 x64.
The code uses Boost 1.54.0, specifically the boost::filesystem library.

The vast majority of my code compiles except for a few function calls when trying to assign strings to a filesystem::path.

For example, if I were to do something as simple as:

```
string path = (char *)"/This/Is/A/Fake/Path";
filesystem::path boostpath = path;
```

I get the following during the link stage:

```
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,class std::codecvt<unsigned short,char,int> const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@$$FYAXPEBG0AEAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV?$codecvt@GDH@5@@Z)
```

I have no idea what is causing this. Other boost libraries, (and Filesystem calls) work just fine!
The only thing that I can think of, is there is something going on with Wide Characters and Windows. Searching around stackoverflow hasn't turned up anything that I can find. The link error itself seems to related to string conversion.

Naturally, this works on Linux/MacOSX.

Thanks in advance!

bob.

Comment: Where did you get the Boost libraries you're using?  Did that package have pre-built libraries for VC 10 or did you build them yourself?  Is the project configured correctly to search the library (which should be a .lib file with `boost_filesystem-vc100` somewhere in the name).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure but this might have something to do with the `/Zc:wchar_t-` option to the MSVC compiler (which turns off native `wchar_t` support).  When `/Zc:wchar_t-` is used, `wchar_t` will be a typedef for `unsigned short` (assuming the appropriate header is included).

Comment: Hi Michael! I compiled the boost library myself, targeted for MSVC 10.0 - (the libs match what you describe.) I set up the package using the prescribed methods on boost.org. ----

So, in a nutshell, I should be compiling boost without this flag? I'll give that a try today. Strange that this flag isn't set properly by bjam or the bootstrap. You would think this is a basic requirement for using paths inside Windows.

Comment: Well, I have change the flag from /Zc:wchar_t to /Zc:wchar_t- in the msvc.jam file and now can compile boost (1.54.0) with a pile of warnings and some failures. It looks as if boost is rather incomplete, when it comes to non-wchar_t support. This is going to be a painful experience. I hate to think that I will have to abandon boost. But it is starting to look this way.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got boost to work with the the the /Zc:wchar_t- switch. This involved editing the "msvc.jam" file. This file is located in your boost source folder.

The path is:  *your-boost-path*/boost_1_54_0/tools/build/v2/tools/msvc.jam

I searched for wchar_t which turned up the **/Zc:wchar_t** flag.
I altered the flag by changing it be **/Zc:wchar_t-**.

The updated line looks like this:

```
 toolset.flags $(toolset).compile CFLAGS $(conditions) : /Zc:forScope /Zc:wchar_t- ;
```

I then compiled boost using the following command line. (I used these flags specifically for my needs.)

```
bjam --toolset=msvc-10.0 architecture=x86 threading=multi link=static address-model=64 --build-type=complete install --prefix=C:\local\boost
```

Once compiled, I gave my project a shot and it seems to work!
I haven't done any serious testing yet, but it seems to compile.

Note: Switching the wchar_t flag resulted in *a lot* of compiler warnings, and a few failures. While I am not using every package that boost offers, I hope that the ones that I need are ok.

Bob..

Comment: Interesting - I've never had to do that. Is it possible that your project that uses Boost has the `/Zc:wchar_t-` option set? If you're using an IDE project to build, then in the VS IDE it shows up in the C++ project properties as 'Language | Treat wchar_t as Built-in Type". It defaults to "Yes" (`/Zc:wchar_t`) since at least VS2008.

Comment: Hi Michael, Indeed, the project that I was working on required the /Zc:wchar_t- flag to be set. This was the root cause of the problem. Unfortunately, this is a legacy issue and I can't switch it back to the more conventional /Zc:wchar_t setting.